# How do I make the game loop back to the beginning after the user has died

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, pygame, adventure

#adventure game
When the user enters the wrong room and die I want it to go back to the question of what room to enter

```
prompt = print("You are in a room by yourself. There are three doors; Red, Blue, and Green. Which door are you picking")
user = input("Room?: ")


def red():
    print("You enter the red room and die")
def blue():
    print("You enter the blue room and freeze to death")
def green():
    print("You enter the green room and proceed")

if user == "r":
        red()
        print(prompt)
elif user == "b":
        blue()
        print(prompt)
elif user == "g":
        green()
        print(prompt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the logic in a `while True` loop.

As long as you don't break out of the loop, it will keep repeating.

Comment: That only prints "You enter the red room and die" Over and over

Comment: You have to redisplay the prompt and ask the question _inside_ the loop, otherwise it reuses the original answer every time.

Comment: heres what i did
```while True:
    prompt = print("You are in a room by yourself. There are three doors; Red, Blue, and Green. Which door are you pickin")
    def red():
        print("You enter the red room and die")
    def blue():
        print("You enter the blue room and freeze")
    def green():
        print("You enter the green room and proceed")

    if user == "r":
            red()
    elif user == "b":
            blue()
    elif user == "g":
            green()
```